# Geo spatial query in IndexedDB

Tags: html, geospatial, indexeddb

I would like to store geopoints and related data in an IndexedDB in the browser and be able to locate the X number of closest points given a lat/long position.  The datasets may include thousands of points, so efficiency is a consideration.  Are there any existing solutions available for this type of query?  How can I build an index so I can locate points close to a given geopoint?

Comment: The answer below lead me in the write direction, but my actual code was different and little more elaborate.  If anyone would like to see code let me know.  Works well and performance is good!

Comment: Hi @Patrick. I'm working with spatial data in inedxedDB, and would love to see the code you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For querying two variables, IndexedDB have two options, manual merging and using compound index.

For manual merging, you only need to index lat and long. Then you will do a key range query on key cursor. Intersection is the result. The results are primary keys. Using result primary keys, you get the full records.

```
var r = 10; // require distance
lat_range = IDBKeyRange.bound(query_lat - r, query_lat + r);
long_range = IDBKeyRange.bound(query_long - r, query_long + r);

obj_store = db.objectStore('geopoint');
lat_key_cursor = obj_store.index('lat').openKeyCursor(lat_range);
long_key_cursor = obj_store.index('long').openKeyCursor(long_range);

// get primary keys from cursors, sort and find intersection as results 
var cursor = obj_store.openCursor(results.shift());
cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.result);
  if (results.length > 0) {
    cursor.continue(results.shift());
  }
}
```

Lat and long can be indexed as array compound index by giving index keyPath as array, ['lat', 'long']. Then you will query a range query of 'lat'. The result of effective key is 'long'. Filter 'long' in the given range and query for the full records.

```
var compound_index = obj_store.index('lat, long');
var range = IDBKeyRange.bound([query_lat - r], [query_lat + r]);
var cursor = compound_index.openKeyCursor(range);
cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
  var key = e.target.result.key();
  var lat = key[0];
  var long = key[1];
  if (long > query_long - r && long < query_long + r) {
     // we get result
     var req = obj_store.get(e.target.result.primaryKey());
     req.onsuccess = function(e2) {
        console.log(e2.target.result);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will try this out.  Do you have any experience with using this code?  What kind of performance could be expected?

Comment: As you can see, it is just key scanning over a range, which computational time is independent of data size. I have no experience in geo query. Being 'ydn-db' database library author, I am very familiar with IndexedDB API.

Comment: +Kyaw just starting to implement this.  I am using IndexedDB shim and it seems to be lacking compoud index support(or I have not found it yet).  I will likely give your lib a try...

Comment: Great! be sure to use latest 0.2.1 release, since it fixed compound index for websql.

Comment: At a loss on how to use this with Ydn-db.  How do you get an object store in ydn-db?

Comment: examples are not using library.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but this solution requires distance `r` ahead of time, whereas the question was about X closest points. How can I know `r` if I only have X?